# get posts from 2 categories. (2 posts)

Tags: categories, get-posts

I have a custom post (it's called "items") and 2 categories there.
1. on category page, I need to get posts which belong to 2 categories.

get posts from category1="Food" and category2="featured"

How can I get these posts from 2 categories?

This is what I have been doing is....

I just got posts from "FOOD" like this. at the same time, I also need to get "featured" from "cate-type2".

I am new here so I have no idea how to put html, php codes.. :)

---

```
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    'post_type' => 'item',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cate-type1',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 39 // Food taxonomy id
        )
    )
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

---

ADDITION CODE: relation and AND

so I need to get posts from 
tax1 : item-special (cate id: 6) 
tax2 : item-category (cate id: 39)

---

`
$custom_terms = get_terms('item-special');
$other_custom_terms = get_terms('item-category');

foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
foreach ($other_custom_terms as $other_custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'item',
        'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'item-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 6
            ),
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'item-special',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => 39
                ),
            ),
             );

```
 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h1 style="margin-top:10px;">'.$custom_term->name.'</h1>';

    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
    endwhile;
 }
```

}
}

### `

I think I have little problems with this code. it shows but duplicated and all item posts.
how should I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now try this, surely it will work

query_posts("cat=1, 2&showposts=5&post_type=item");

while(have_posts()) : the_post();

```
echo $title = get_the_title();
echo $content = get_the_content();
```

endwhile;

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. it shows all of item (custom post type) I put `array(6, 39)` but it doesn't work. any tips?

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: hello balamurugan, thanks for your time. when I put cat=6,39 it is not showing anything. I have tried others on wp-codex. but it's not showing any result when I put cat or category__and.... //query_posts("cat=6&showposts=5&post_type=ait-dir-item");
 //query_posts("cat=6,39&showposts=5&post_type=ait-dir-item");
 //query_posts("showposts=5&post_type=ait-dir-item");

only the last one is working but showing all of them.

Comment: query_posts( array( post_type=>'ait-dir-item', 'category__and' => array(6,39), 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
query_posts( array( post_type=>'ait-dir-item', 'category' => 39, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
These are not working as well when I add 'category__and', 'category'. without them, it works. but showing all of items.

Thanks for your time again, please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: @toscho I will add how to solve my problem, when I figure it out. thanks all.

Comment: I found that custom categories need some more thing to add. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` relation between `tax_query`

```
$posts = get_posts(  array( 'numberposts'   => -1,
                            'post_type'     => 'post_type',
                            'tax_query'     => array('relation'=> 'AND',
                                                        array(  'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy_1',
                                                                'field'     => 'id',
                                                                'terms'     => 'taxonomy_id_1'
                                                                )),
                                                        array(  'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy_id_2',
                                                                'field'     => 'id',
                                                                'terms'     => 'taxonomy_id_2'
                                                                )),
                            'meta_query'    => array(array( 'key' => 'meta_key',
                                                            'value' => 'meta_value'
                                                            ))
                                            )
                                    );
```

Comment: I added new codes, please see what I have done wrong. 
Thanks for your time and help